# Fill the steps (randomly)!

Tags: code-golf, sequence, array, random, apl

**This is Hole-9 from [*The Autumn Tournament* of APL CodeGolf](https://apl.codegolf.co.uk/problems#9). I am the original author of the problem there, and thus allowed to re-post it here.**

---

Given a simple (rectangular, non-jagged) Boolean array (of one or more dimensions) return a list of thusly shaped arrays where the first array is identical to the input and the last is all-true. All intermediary steps must have one more truth than its neighbor to the left (but otherwise be identical). For each step, the bit that is changed must be pseudo-randomly chosen (and you may take a seed if necessary).

#### Examples

`[0]` gives `[[0],[1]]`

`[[0]]` gives `[[[0]],[[1]]]`

`[[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]]` gives `[[[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]]]`

The following examples' results may of course vary due to randomness; these are just examples of valid output:

`[0,1,0,0]` gives `[[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1]]`

`[[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]` gives `[[[0,1,0],[0,0,1]],[[1,1,0],[0,0,1]],[[1,1,0],[0,1,1]],[[1,1,1],[0,1,1]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]]`

`[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]` gives `[[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]],[[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]],[[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]],[[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]],[[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]]`

Comment: These challenges have really made me start to question the decisions the R/S developers made...

Comment: @Giuseppe R/S developers?

Comment: R (and S-plus) is an implementation of S, so a lot of the base R functions operate the way that S specifies them, or are maintained to allow compatibility with S (or worse, S-plus). I'm not sure who to blame for some of the unexpected behaviors I've encountered while attempting to solve some of these challenges!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
F¬0TX$¦ÐĿ¬ṁ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t0BqDkAiVQ8sOTziy/9CahzsbHzWt@X@4/eikhztnAJmRCg93bH/UMEfBOTEnRyEnMy9bTyGgKDOvRCE1MTlDIbMktSixJDM/TwGIEhXyUstBalL1/v@Pjo420FEwiNVRgNAgBrKIIaqIIVgkFgA)

#### How it works

```
F¬0TX$¦ÐĿ¬ṁ€  Main link. Argument: A (array)

F             Flatten A.
 ¬            Negate all Booleans in the result.
       DĿ     Repeatedly call the link to the left until the results are no longer
              unique. Yield the array of all unique results.
      ¦         Sparse application:
   TX$            Pseudo-randomly select an index of a 1.
  0               Replace the element at that index with 0.
         ¬    Once again negate all Booleans.
          ṁ€  Shape each flat array in the result like A.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 197 bytes

```python
import random,copy
A=[input()]
while"0"in`A[-1]`:
 A+=copy.deepcopy(A[-1]),
 while~0:
	j="A[-1]"
	while[]<eval(j):j+="[%s]"%random.randint(0,~-len(eval(j)))
	if eval(j)<1:exec"%s=1"%j;break
print A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xY9BasMwEEXXnlOIAYNElCB1aUcL42MIQdxEJXIdWThu0mxydVdSTaAn6J/FzLz/xaDwmM@jf1tahYiLu4RxmsnU@dN44ccxPKBR2vnwNVNm4H52g0WBzh8avZXmUAFpNirldidrQxpodhgHktNPUUHRK8wUochQm729dQPtWdVvFOryarD8PbpLzfmZCv7cDtbTNcgYFO6DrNteVvbbHrG8KollX79PtvuEMMWHpFniT@ps52OkzVnS1tnHRSdJkwT6JWFeilRwyYXhscdpJX9q9f6LmB8)

Answer (score 1):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 61 bytes

```
FoldList[ReplacePart[#,#2->1]&,#,RandomSample@Position[#,0]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y0/J8Uns7gkOii1ICcxOTUgsagkWllH2UjXzjBWTUdZJygxLyU/NzgxtyAn1SEgvzizJDM/D6jCIDZW7X9AUWZeiYKDlkKagr6DQjWXgkK1Qa0OiALSUEa1oQ4Q1uqg0UAG6TIQIw2AHAMduEUgHlAJUASkhKv2PwA)

#### Explanation

```
Position[#,0]
```

Find all positions of `0`s in the nested array.

```
RandomSample@...
```

Shuffle the list of positions.

```
FoldList[...&,#,...]
```

Fold the function on the left over the shuffled list of positions, using the input as the starting value, and collect all steps of the fold operation in the result.

```
ReplacePart[#,#2->1]
```

Set the value at the given position to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>93</s> <s>82</s> 74 bytes

```r
function(a)Reduce(function(x,y){x[y]=T;x},sample(as.list(which(!a))),a,,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcy9CsIwFIbhvVdxxOUEjg6ZAurqBUg3cTimCS2krSQpJojXHv9QF3F9v4fPF9cdPfuMvYnt2ARRWVgvoNhp0LEbB2SxM82kDX5KoiwuaZ8Pm3qVrhS4PzmDHJauCxHPbadbnLEQgpioFsUie88Zt6RRkrwPMAeZJDwzjBbYObDsgqnetv5ro5@@9HGrSL2oSurHbbkB)

Takes an R `logical` `array` and returns a `list` of `logical` `array`s.

The nasty `sample(as.list(which(!a)))` is to prevent an edge case in `sample`. When `a` contains exactly one `FALSE` value at index `i`, `sample` returns a random permutation of `1:i` rather than a random sample of size `1` containing only the value `i`, so I used `as.list` to prevent `which(!a)` from being `numeric`.

The R documentation for `sample` is mildly apologetic about this behavior:

> If `x` has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of `is.numeric`) and `x >= 1`, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x. ***Note* that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour when x is of varying length in calls such as `sample(x)`.**

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 78 + 1 (`-p`) = 79 bytes

```perl
while(@a=/0/g){$o.="$_,";for$i(0..rand@a){/0/g}substr$_,-1+pos,1,1}$_="[$o$_]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsMgEAD/IntIqJr1kFMR8oG8QEQsTVshZEVTegj5erf2NMMweSnryPx5pXXppmgHHJ79AaStgCDF9UEFUodal7jdp9gf/@Gs71vdSxuUuWSq0khzQrDCAUHwgtk5bBG9bGzm/ZfynmirrOZRo0FW@Qc)

Array?  What array?  It's just a long string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
F¬TṬ€$$o€$ṁ€µX$ÐĿṖṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t0JqQhzvXPGpao6KSDyIf7mwEUoe2RqgcnnBk/8Od04Do////0dEGOkAYqwOlYwE)

Probably could be shorter

## Explanation

```
F¬TṬ€$$o€$ṁ€µX$ÐĿṖṖ  Main Link
               ÐĿ    While results are unique:
F                    Flatten the array
     $$              3 links will form a monad
 ¬                   Logical NOT on each element
  T                  Find indices of 1s (0s in the original)
    €                For each 0 in the original
   Ṭ                 Make an array of all 0s containing one 1 there
         $           2 links will form a monad
        €            For each of the mask arrays
       o             Vectorizing logical OR it with the original (flat) array
           €         For each of these subarrays
          ṁ          Reshape it to the original array's shape
            µ        Start a new monadic chain, using the list of possible next steps as the argument
              $      2 links will form a monad
             X       Pick a random element
                 ṖṖ  Remove the last two elements (0 and '' which are selected by X when the list is empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>134</s> <s>132</s> 129 bytes

```python
from random import*
a=input()
print a;l=list(`a`)
while'0'in l:l[choice([i for i,c in enumerate(l)if'0'==c])]='1';print''.join(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BCsMgFET3nuKTjRqkmHbX4klEiBhDfjEq1tD29FbS1XswwzD5W7cUr82lxYOCYRjaWtIOxcalA/ecSh2JVRjzURknuWCsYB9BBXxVNtuZk/eGwVNJMUK4B@22hM4zjbCmAigc9MDHY/fFVs8Cx7WXlXKGG0Un@jg3Kb08E8Yet/6CEP/xDs5bI9ya1tIYoqWYhBSy21@N6OxmzA8)